# Replacing feed_dict in TF2.0 for tensor inputs to tensors in a function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a Keras Callback that retrieves values from particular Keras layers like so:

```
def run(self, fetches, next_batch):
    """Run fetches using the validation data passed in during initialization."""
    input_data, target_data = self.sess.run(next_batch)
    feed_dict = {self.model.inputs[0]: input_data,
                 self.model._targets[0]: target_data}
    result = self.sess.run(fetches=fetches, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    return result
```

`next_batch` was a Dataset.make_one_shot_iterator.get_next() call in tf1. I've replaced it with next(iter(ds)). That part works fine.

However I cannot figure out how to rewrite the sess.run() call. I want to get output from the 'fetches' tensors, but their inputs are other tensors higher up in the Model. I know which tensors are my input tensors, but how do I pass data into them and get the outputs I want from the tensors in later layers?

I read the [conversion documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) on this subject but it is REALLY terse and unhelpful. I was not able to find much more information on stackoverflow.

Comment: TF 2.0 do not require `session()` or `eager execution`

Comment: I know, but how do I pass data into the model in the tf 2.0? Do I have to define the whole graph inside the function?

Comment: you can pass data in model by calling the model `model=MyModel()` and then pass the data `model(input_data)`

Comment: That doesn't work because I'm not trying to just run the model- I need to return the values of certain tensors from the middle of the model, not just the output layers. It used to be possible in TF1 by passing those tensors to session.run() with a feed_dict.

Comment: if you want the outputs of the layer then you can use `out1 = model.get_layer(layer_name).output` and then build the model by `Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=out1)`

Comment: That is a very interesting approach- I'm not sure I want to construct a new Model, but it's something to consider.

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat well I tested it and it does work! If you add it as an answer I'll accept it. And thanks!

Comment: I am glad it worked,I have posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the specific layer could be fetched from the model in this way

```py
#get the output from the layer1
out1 = model.get_layer(layer1_name).output

#get the output from the layer2 
out2 = model.get_layer(layer2_name).output

#a new model with outputs of the layers
MyModel = Model(inputs=model.input,outputs=[out1,out2])
```

Now you can pass the values like

```py
#call the model
mymodel = MyModel()

#pass your inputs
outputs = mymodel(inputs)
```

Remember the `outputs` is the  array of the both the outputs which can be fetched by

```py
output1 = outputs[0]
output2 = outputs[1]
```